# What is the easiest way to create specific plane consists of point clouds?

Tags: c++, 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, plane

I use the PCL with C++, and I would like to create a plane using coefficients of Ax + By + Cz = D. For instance, I would like to create a plane like front side of the pyramid. What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but **you know** the coefficients and want to create a plane. I believe this is what you are looking for (https://pointclouds.org/documentation/group__visualization.html#ga3d7d6b7f35877b9feb237e898094c01e):

```
pcl::ModelCoefficients plane_coeff;
plane_coeff.values.resize (4);    // We need 4 values
plane_coeff.values[0] = A;
plane_coeff.values[1] = B;
plane_coeff.values[2] = C;
plane_coeff.values[3] = -D;
 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSet> data = pcl::visualization::createPlane (plane_coeff);
```

It's `-D` because in the documentation, equation for a plane is given as **(a, b, c, d with ax+by+cz+d=0)**.